# Ctrl + V pastes in MacVim, instead of going to visual block select

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

I have two different Macs, both with recently updated MacOS, and both with identical installations of MacVim version 8.2 from homebrew (built on the same day, with the same options, according to :version). My .vimrc is identical on the two machines.

One one machine, ctrl + v goes to block visual mode in MacVim (the gui version), on the other machine, ctrl + v pastes from the clipboard. On both machines, ctrl + v works as expected (visual block) when I open vim in the terminal (iTerm2).

This is driving me somewhat crazy. How can I get the same behaviour on both machines?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is `:behave ms-win` or similar got triggered somehow

Comment: I'd never heard of that before, and I don't seem to have any help installed for behave, but with the help of tab completion I found that the only two options for behave seem to be mswin and xterm, and in both cases ctrl+V continues to paste instead of going to visual block.

Comment: Try help mswin... they basically source some vimscripts that set up these (imo obnoxious) mappings